# Vaadin Notifications with cron job

Tags: vaadin

In my application, I want to display notification to the user according to the cronjob(periodically) ,In vaadin we can use Notification and the PopView for this , but seems like its not working as I expected(It does not display the notification or popup according to the cronjob,user have to click UI to display the notification) , I have another requirement. Notification should display until user click on the notification,when use click on the notification, System should popup the window with notification information, Is there any component which I can use for this in Vaadin

Thank you

Cheers

Udeshika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP protocol lacks a server-side push. So, when you create a notification in a background thread Vaadin still needs a request from client browser to show a notification
So, I assume you need:

- Background thread checking for cron job and showing notifications if necessary.
- Client side component that will periodically poll the server for updates. You have several options:

  - [ProgressIndicator](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/ProgressIndicator.html) has a polling functionality. Add this component to a window and use `setPollingInterval` method to set update interval.
  - Try to use [Refresher](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/77099) plugin.

[Updating UI from another thread](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/231271) - relevant discussion on vaadin.com

Comment: Thank you , That's what I was thinking about,I have to use that mechanism to over come that problem